# How do i pass value from one activity to another activity

Tags: php, android

How do i pass the value which is the subjetfile.getSubjectID from the ListView to another activity which is SubjectActivity, so that $id=$_GET['subjectID']; in my php code won't be null? Anyone can help? I have a list of subject which place inside a listView, i would like to pass it to SubjectActivity when i click any item in the listView, and the activity display the detail of the subject, but the php code seems not working because of the $id. If anyone can help i will be appreciate, thanks!

```js
public class SubjectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageViewDefault;
    private TextView textViewDefaultName;
    private TextView textViewDefaultDescription1;
    private TextView textViewDefaultDescription2;
    private static final String GET_URL_SUBJECT = "https://arlearn.000webhostapp.com/getSubject.php";
    private static final int TAG1 = 1;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private subjectFile subjectfile;
    private String result = null;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        imageViewDefault = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewSubject);
        textViewDefaultName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewDefaultDescription1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewContent1);
        textViewDefaultDescription2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewContent2);
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.subject, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            getSubjectContent(getApplicationContext(), GET_URL_SUBJECT);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void getSubjectContent(Context context, String url) {
        RequestQueue request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.setMessage("Syn with server...");
        pDialog.show();


        JsonArrayRequest requestsubject = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        try {
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                                JSONObject subjectResponse = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                                String name = subjectResponse.getString("name");
                                String image = subjectResponse.getString("image");
                                String description1 = subjectResponse.getString("Description1");
                                String description2 = subjectResponse.getString("Description2");
                                subjectfile = new subjectFile(name, image, description1, description2);
                            }
                            loadFile();
                            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                                pDialog.dismiss();
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error:" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+result+"]");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                error.printStackTrace();
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    );
        request.add(requestsubject);
    }

    private void loadFile() {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        imageBytes = Base64.decode(subjectfile.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodeImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
        imageViewDefault.setImageBitmap(decodeImage);
        textViewDefaultName.setText(subjectfile.getName());
        textViewDefaultDescription1.setText(subjectfile.getDescription1());
        textViewDefaultDescription2.setText(subjectfile.getDescription2());
    }

}
```

```css
<?php
 include("connection1.php");

 // connecting to db
 $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost, $username_localhost, $password_localhost, $database_localhost);

 /* check connection */
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Error: Connect failed: %s\n";
  exit();
 }

 $response = array();
 

 $id=$_GET['subjectID'];
 
 $query = "SELECT image, name, Description1, Description2 from subject WHERE subjectID = ".$id;
 
 
 /* Select queries return a resultset */
 if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $query))
 {
     $response = array();
     
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
     {
         $item = array();
         $item["image"] = base64_encode($row["image"]);
      $item["name"] = $row["name"];
      $item["Description1"] = $row["Description1"];
      $item["Description2"] = $row["Description2"];
      array_push($response, $item);
     }
     mysqli_free_result($result);
 }

 else{
     $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";
 }
 
 echo json_encode($response);
 /* close connection */
 mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

```html
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                subjectFile subjectfile = imageAdapter.getItem(position);
                Log.i("Database", subjectfile.getSubjectID());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SubjectActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow it -

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                subjectFile subjectfile = imageAdapter.getItem(position);
                Log.i("Database", subjectfile.getSubjectID());
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SubjectActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("subject_id", subjectfile.getSubjectID());
startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Access that intent on `SubjectActivity` activity's `onCreate()` method.

```
String subjectId = getIntent().getStringExtra("subject_id");
```

Comment: How do i do it so $id in my php can get the subjectId also?

Comment: php script is on server of course. so you need to implement network call. better you use any network library, such as volley, android networkng etc are good network library.

Comment: so i need to do another StringRequest to insert the subjectID?

Comment: How did you get list of subject id? by httpRequest?

Comment: i get it from JsonArrayRequest, sorry for that i am still new to android development

Comment: Cant you get all of these data by single request?

Comment: i get it, i can pass in through url

Comment: Great. If my answer helps you, then plz accept it and make upvote. thanks